# Can we use logic apps to get click count on Sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

Can we use logic apps or Power Automate (Flow) to get a click count on our Sharepoint online site.  We want to record the name of the person who has clicked on a page.
We have a request based flow, but that is triggered by adding Javascript to the webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, go through all of the actions for SharePoint, I think we can not implement this requirement in logic app. We can just do it as you mentioned triggered by javascript.